# Java BigDecimal error?

Tags: java, sdk, bigdecimal

Solved:

** just got an email from Oracle that they resolved this issue in JDK ver 8u40. I never received their notice. So this problem is moot.

---

I previously posted this issue ([Does anyone know if this is a Java library bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878857/does-anyone-know-if-this-is-a-java-library-bug?noredirect=1#comment46240282_28878857)) but didn't have a concise test program. Now I do. Can someone see if I'm overlooking something in the code, or run it and verify that it's not something in my environment?

Below is the code and the output. The last 4 lines show the problem. I suspect it's not the value of PI that matters but the fact that it has 1515 decimal places. NOTE that if the line setting SCALE=1000 decimal places is used instead of 1500, the program will produce the correct result at the end, for pi*10^595. btw, I know the last line, with toString(), is redundant; it was part of a larger test and is a remnant.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class testBigDecimal
{
  public  static  void    main(String args[])
  {
    new testBigDecimal().test();
  }

  private void    test()
  {
    BigDecimal  PI;
    BigDecimal  TWO_PI;

//      int SCALE = 1000;       // xxxxxxx  THIS WORKS
        int SCALE = 1500;       // xxxxxxx  THIS FAILS

    PI = new BigDecimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046684259069491293313677028989152104752162056966024058038150193511253382430035587640247496473263914199272604269922796782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302952311877082277576");
    TWO_PI = PI.multiply( new BigDecimal("2") ) .setScale(SCALE,BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

    System.out.println("\r\n TWO_PI = " + TWO_PI);

    // -------------------------------------------
    // first try -- CORRECT RESULT for movePointRight()

    BigDecimal x = TWO_PI;

    int places = 70;
    BigInteger ix = x.movePointRight(places).toBigInteger();
    System.out.println("\r\n         places = " + places);
    System.out.println(    "           x = TWO_PI = " + x);
    System.out.println(    " right(places).int( ) = " + ix);
    System.out.println("");

    BigDecimal shiftX = x.movePointRight(places);
    String sx = x.movePointRight(places).toString();
    System.out.println("  x.movePointRight(x) = " + shiftX);
    System.out.println("     String for above = " + sx);


    // -------------------------------------------
    // second try -- INCORRECT RESULT for movePointRight()

    System.out.println("\r\n-------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("\r\n TWO_PI = " + TWO_PI);

    x = TWO_PI;

    places = 595;
    ix = x.movePointRight(places).toBigInteger();
    System.out.println("\r\n         places = " + places);
    System.out.println(    "           x = TWO_PI = " + x);
    System.out.println(    " right(places).int( ) = " + ix);
    System.out.println("");

    // wrong:
    shiftX = x.movePointRight(places);
    sx = x.movePointRight(places).toString();
    System.out.println("  x.movePointRight(x) = " + shiftX);
    System.out.println("     String for above = " + sx);
  }
}
```

---

Output:

```
TWO_PI = 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641949889184615632812572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547449174013212631176349763041841925658508183430728735785180720022661061097640933042768293903883023218866114540731519183906184372234763865223586210237096148924759925499134703771505449782455876366023898259667346724881313286172042789892790449474381404359721887405541078434352586353504769349636935338810264001136254290527121655571542685515579218347274357442936881802449906860293099170742101584559378517847084039912224258043921728068836319627259549542619921037414422699999996745956099902119463465632192637190048918910693816605285044616506689370070523862376342020006275677505773175066416762841234355338294607196506980857510937462319125727764707575187503915563715561064342453613226003855753222391818432840397876190514402130971726557731872306763655936460603904070603705937991547245198827782499443550566958263031149714484908301391901659066233723455711778150196763509274929878638510120801855403342278019697648025716723207127415320209420363885911192397893535674898896510759549453694208095069292416093368518138982586627354057978304209504324113932048116076300387022506764860071175280494992946527828398545208539845593564709563272018683443282439849172630060572365949111413499677010989177173853991381854421595018605904

places = 70
x = TWO_PI = 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641949889184615632812572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547449174013212631176349763041841925658508183430728735785180720022661061097640933042768293903883023218866114540731519183906184372234763865223586210237096148924759925499134703771505449782455876366023898259667346724881313286172042789892790449474381404359721887405541078434352586353504769349636935338810264001136254290527121655571542685515579218347274357442936881802449906860293099170742101584559378517847084039912224258043921728068836319627259549542619921037414422699999996745956099902119463465632192637190048918910693816605285044616506689370070523862376342020006275677505773175066416762841234355338294607196506980857510937462319125727764707575187503915563715561064342453613226003855753222391818432840397876190514402130971726557731872306763655936460603904070603705937991547245198827782499443550566958263031149714484908301391901659066233723455711778150196763509274929878638510120801855403342278019697648025716723207127415320209420363885911192397893535674898896510759549453694208095069292416093368518138982586627354057978304209504324113932048116076300387022506764860071175280494992946527828398545208539845593564709563272018683443282439849172630060572365949111413499677010989177173853991381854421595018605904
right(places).int( ) = 62831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502116419498891846156328

x.movePointRight(x) = 62831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502116419498891846156328.12572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547449174013212631176349763041841925658508183430728735785180720022661061097640933042768293903883023218866114540731519183906184372234763865223586210237096148924759925499134703771505449782455876366023898259667346724881313286172042789892790449474381404359721887405541078434352586353504769349636935338810264001136254290527121655571542685515579218347274357442936881802449906860293099170742101584559378517847084039912224258043921728068836319627259549542619921037414422699999996745956099902119463465632192637190048918910693816605285044616506689370070523862376342020006275677505773175066416762841234355338294607196506980857510937462319125727764707575187503915563715561064342453613226003855753222391818432840397876190514402130971726557731872306763655936460603904070603705937991547245198827782499443550566958263031149714484908301391901659066233723455711778150196763509274929878638510120801855403342278019697648025716723207127415320209420363885911192397893535674898896510759549453694208095069292416093368518138982586627354057978304209504324113932048116076300387022506764860071175280494992946527828398545208539845593564709563272018683443282439849172630060572365949111413499677010989177173853991381854421595018605904
String for above = 62831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502116419498891846156328.12572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547449174013212631176349763041841925658508183430728735785180720022661061097640933042768293903883023218866114540731519183906184372234763865223586210237096148924759925499134703771505449782455876366023898259667346724881313286172042789892790449474381404359721887405541078434352586353504769349636935338810264001136254290527121655571542685515579218347274357442936881802449906860293099170742101584559378517847084039912224258043921728068836319627259549542619921037414422699999996745956099902119463465632192637190048918910693816605285044616506689370070523862376342020006275677505773175066416762841234355338294607196506980857510937462319125727764707575187503915563715561064342453613226003855753222391818432840397876190514402130971726557731872306763655936460603904070603705937991547245198827782499443550566958263031149714484908301391901659066233723455711778150196763509274929878638510120801855403342278019697648025716723207127415320209420363885911192397893535674898896510759549453694208095069292416093368518138982586627354057978304209504324113932048116076300387022506764860071175280494992946527828398545208539845593564709563272018683443282439849172630060572365949111413499677010989177173853991381854421595018605904

-------------------------------------------

TWO_PI = 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641949889184615632812572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547449174013212631176349763041841925658508183430728735785180720022661061097640933042768293903883023218866114540731519183906184372234763865223586210237096148924759925499134703771505449782455876366023898259667346724881313286172042789892790449474381404359721887405541078434352586353504769349636935338810264001136254290527121655571542685515579218347274357442936881802449906860293099170742101584559378517847084039912224258043921728068836319627259549542619921037414422699999996745956099902119463465632192637190048918910693816605285044616506689370070523862376342020006275677505773175066416762841234355338294607196506980857510937462319125727764707575187503915563715561064342453613226003855753222391818432840397876190514402130971726557731872306763655936460603904070603705937991547245198827782499443550566958263031149714484908301391901659066233723455711778150196763509274929878638510120801855403342278019697648025716723207127415320209420363885911192397893535674898896510759549453694208095069292416093368518138982586627354057978304209504324113932048116076300387022506764860071175280494992946527828398545208539845593564709563272018683443282439849172630060572365949111413499677010989177173853991381854421595018605904

places = 595
x = TWO_PI = 6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394338798750211641949889184615632812572417997256069650684234135964296173026564613294187689219101164463450718816256962234900568205403877042211119289245897909860763928857621951331866892256951296467573566330542403818291297133846920697220908653296426787214520498282547449174013212631176349763041841925658508183430728735785180720022661061097640933042768293903883023218866114540731519183906184372234763865223586210237096148924759925499134703771505449782455876366023898259667346724881313286172042789892790449474381404359721887405541078434352586353504769349636935338810264001136254290527121655571542685515579218347274357442936881802449906860293099170742101584559378517847084039912224258043921728068836319627259549542619921037414422699999996745956099902119463465632192637190048918910693816605285044616506689370070523862376342020006275677505773175066416762841234355338294607196506980857510937462319125727764707575187503915563715561064342453613226003855753222391818432840397876190514402130971726557731872306763655936460603904070603705937991547245198827782499443550566958263031149714484908301391901659066233723455711778150196763509274929878638510120801855403342278019697648025716723207127415320209420363885911192397893535674898896510759549453694208095069292416093368518138982586627354057978304209504324113932048116076300387022506764860071175280494992946527828398545208539845593564709563272018683443282439849172630060572365949111413499677010989177173853991381854421595018605904
right(places).int( ) = 62831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502116419498891846156328125724179972560696506842341359642961730265646132941876892191011644634507188162569622349005682054038770422111192892458979098607639288576219513318668922569512964675735663305424038182912971338469206972209086532964267872145204982825474491740132126311763497630418419256585081834307287357851807200226610610976409330427682939038830232188661145407315191839061843722347638652235862102370961489247599254991347037715054497824558763660238982596673467248813132861720427898927904494743814043597218874055410784343525863535047693496369353388

x.movePointRight(x) = 125663706143591729538505735331180115367886775975004232838997783692312656251448359945121393013684682719285923460531292265883753784382023289269014376325139244698011364108077540844222385784917958197215278577152439026637337845139025929351471326610848076365825942676938413944418173065928535744290409965650948983480264252623526995260836838513170163668614574715703614400453221221952818660855365878077660464377322290814630383678123687444695277304471724204741922978495198509982694075430108995649117527320477965193346934497626265723440855797855808989487628087194437748110821568687051727070095386992738706776.20528002272508581054243311143085371031158436694548714885873763604899813720586198341484203169118757035694168079824448516087843456137672639254519099085239842074828845399999993491912199804238926931264385274380097837821387633210570089233013378740141047724752684040012551355011546350132833525682468710676589214393013961715021874924638251455529415150375007831127431122128684907226452007711506444783636865680795752381028804261943453115463744613527311872921207808141207411875983094490397655564998887101133916526062299428969816602783803318132467446911423556300393527018549859757277020241603710806684556039395296051433446414254830640418840727771822384795787071349797793021519098907388416190138584832186737036277965173254708115956608419008648227864096232152600774045013529720142350560989985893055656797090417079691187129419126544037366886564879698345260121144731898222826999354021978354347707982763708843190037211808
String for above = 125663706143591729538505735331180115367886775975004232838997783692312656251448359945121393013684682719285923460531292265883753784382023289269014376325139244698011364108077540844222385784917958197215278577152439026637337845139025929351471326610848076365825942676938413944418173065928535744290409965650948983480264252623526995260836838513170163668614574715703614400453221221952818660855365878077660464377322290814630383678123687444695277304471724204741922978495198509982694075430108995649117527320477965193346934497626265723440855797855808989487628087194437748110821568687051727070095386992738706776.20528002272508581054243311143085371031158436694548714885873763604899813720586198341484203169118757035694168079824448516087843456137672639254519099085239842074828845399999993491912199804238926931264385274380097837821387633210570089233013378740141047724752684040012551355011546350132833525682468710676589214393013961715021874924638251455529415150375007831127431122128684907226452007711506444783636865680795752381028804261943453115463744613527311872921207808141207411875983094490397655564998887101133916526062299428969816602783803318132467446911423556300393527018549859757277020241603710806684556039395296051433446414254830640418840727771822384795787071349797793021519098907388416190138584832186737036277965173254708115956608419008648227864096232152600774045013529720142350560989985893055656797090417079691187129419126544037366886564879698345260121144731898222826999354021978354347707982763708843190037211808
```

---

With the value SCALE=1000 used, these are the last 2 output lines:

```
x.movePointRight(x) = 62831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502116419498891846156328125724179972560696506842341359642961730265646132941876892191011644634507188162569622349005682054038770422111192892458979098607639288576219513318668922569512964675735663305424038182912971338469206972209086532964267872145204982825474491740132126311763497630418419256585081834307287357851807200226610610976409330427682939038830232188661145407315191839061843722347638652235862102370961489247599254991347037715054497824558763660238982596673467248813132861720427898927904494743814043597218874055410784343525863535047693496369353388.102640011362542905271216555715426855155792183472743574429368818024499068602930991707421015845593785178470840399122242580439217280688363196272595495426199210374144226999999967459560999021194634656321926371900489189106938166052850446165066893700705238623763420200062756775057731750664167628412343553382946071965069808575109374623191257277647075751875039155637155610643424536132260038557532223918184328403978
String for above = 62831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502116419498891846156328125724179972560696506842341359642961730265646132941876892191011644634507188162569622349005682054038770422111192892458979098607639288576219513318668922569512964675735663305424038182912971338469206972209086532964267872145204982825474491740132126311763497630418419256585081834307287357851807200226610610976409330427682939038830232188661145407315191839061843722347638652235862102370961489247599254991347037715054497824558763660238982596673467248813132861720427898927904494743814043597218874055410784343525863535047693496369353388.102640011362542905271216555715426855155792183472743574429368818024499068602930991707421015845593785178470840399122242580439217280688363196272595495426199210374144226999999967459560999021194634656321926371900489189106938166052850446165066893700705238623763420200062756775057731750664167628412343553382946071965069808575109374623191257277647075751875039155637155610643424536132260038557532223918184328403978
```

Comment: @fge: Thanks. Deleting comment.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - I get the correct output, even with scale = 1500. What version of java do you use? Are you sure that's the code you are running - could it be that you are running a previous version of your code that had a bug?

Comment: It looks like it is a bug that got fixed in Java 8u40.

Comment: Thanks for resolving this. It's a really weird bug. The program `BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("1").setScale(1380);x.movePointRight(595).toBigInteger();System.out.println(x.movePointRight(595));` was printing `655360000000...`

Answer (score 0):

@pbabcdefp  fyi, the Oracle docs indicated an internal variable "tau" wasn't scaled correctly. tau is = 2*pi. Not sure where a circle is used in scaling but it's not surprising given many numerical methods used for efficiency.

Also, I found that 1415 decimal places was the thresshold for the failure.. I wonder if 1415 being the first 4 decimal places of pi is of any relevance. I also found (as you did) that the wrong test result is always a multiple of 2^k of the correct value, for random values of k.

Also fyi, apparently 'tau' is someone's idea that Archimedes got it wrong that pi should be the basic circle constant, and 2*pi should have been. Personally I think it's funny that someone would think Archimedes should have envisioned the results of Euler, etc and that history didn't happen correctly. But the bug is fixed in JDK 8u45 for sure, which is what I downloaded, and it's supposed to be fixed in 8u40.